# how to make css border not affecting the area of content

Tags: html, css, border, gradient

i have a grid item (instagram button) that have instagram color gradient (using css) as the background but it doesnt fully cover the whole element because i used `border-top`.

```
.instagram{
      border-top: 1px solid rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.486);
      background: -webkit-radial-gradient(30% 107%, circle, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
      background: -o-radial-gradient(30% 107%, circle, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
      background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
      background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
   }
```

[gradient not fully covering the grid item because of border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiN9b.png)

i tried `background-attachment: fixed`.

and `outline` is out of question because it will give outline to all sides (only need top side). is there a way for it to make the gradient full while keeping the `border-top`? or any workaround. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudoelement can always solve problem like this.

1. Remove the border-top from your .instagram div.
2. Make that div relatively positioned (`position: relative;`) to allow it to accept an absolutely positioned child, which is the number 3 below.
3. Create an ::after or ::before pseudoelement for your .instagram div. Give it `position:absolute;` so that its dimension can be freely adjusted relative to the parent, make its content blank (`content: ' ';`) because we only need its border top, set its left, top, width, and height so that it attaches firmly to .instagram, and give it the border top.

```css
.instagram {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 150px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(
    30% 107%,
    circle,
    #fdf497 0%,
    #fdf497 5%,
    #fd5949 45%,
    #d6249f 60%,
    #285aeb 90%
  );
  background: -o-radial-gradient(
    30% 107%,
    circle,
    #fdf497 0%,
    #fdf497 5%,
    #fd5949 45%,
    #d6249f 60%,
    #285aeb 90%
  );
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle at 30% 107%,
    #fdf497 0%,
    #fdf497 5%,
    #fd5949 45%,
    #d6249f 60%,
    #285aeb 90%
  );
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(
    circle at 30% 107%,
    #fdf497 0%,
    #fdf497 5%,
    #fd5949 45%,
    #d6249f 60%,
    #285aeb 90%
  );
}

.instagram::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-top: 10px solid rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.486);
  border-radius: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="instagram"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yay it worked! but now the `hover` doesnt work. i suppose the cursor doesnt touch the element when hovering? am i correct? any workaround? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it using pseudo-elements

- Add a pseudo-element `::before` to your `.instagram` class.
- Style the pseudo-element with the gradient background and set its position to absolute and top: -1px. This will create an element on top of your button that covers the entire area behind the border.
- Adjust the width and height of the pseudo-element to match the dimensions of your button

```
.instagram {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.486);
  position: relative; /* Needed for positioning the pseudo-element */
}

.instagram::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(30% 107%, circle, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(30% 107%, circle, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  /* You can also set the width and height to be more explicit */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```